# Are there any useful deterministic quantum algorithms for decision problems?

Tags: algorithms, quantum-computing, probabilistic-algorithms

The vast majority of known interesting quantum algorithms are probabilistic.  The only deterministic quantum algorithms that I know of (which aren't trivially equivalent to a classical algorithm) are (a) Deutsch's algorithm, in which the quantum speedup is pretty trivial, (b) the Deutsch-Josza algorithm, which solves a promise problem rather than a decision problem, and (c) this algorithm (which I found by Googling): http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5848, which also doesn't solve a decision problem.  Are there other known examples of "interesting"/"useful" deterministic quantum algorithms, especially for decision problems?

I know that this question isn't particularly well-formulated, because which algorithms you can use depends on which set of quantum gates you have available.  Are there any interesting algorithms that use only a "realistic" set of quantum gates?  (Say, only the quantum gates that can be currently purchased on Amazon for under $10 :-) .)

Comment: "Say, only the quantum gates that can be currently purchased on Amazon for under \$10". If they were useful for practical problems, they would probably cost a lot more than $10.

Comment: @jmite Until the patent expires, sure.  After that, competition between suppliers would drive the price down to the marginal cost of production.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question: are you asking if there are any interesting algorithms that use no quantum gates at all? quantum gates that can be simulated for $10 worth of actual, existing (hence non-quantum) computers?

Comment: @Gilles The reference to $10 was completely a joke - I was making the point that it's hard to say what will be a "realistic" quantum gate , considering we have not yet succeeded in creating any reliable quantum gates at all.  For the purpose of my question, by "realistic quantum gate" I mean, say, the gates described in the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some query complexity results that mention exact quantum algorithms. See [this blog post](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2325) about the paper "[Separations in Query Complexity Based on Pointer Functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04719)":

> a total boolean function $g$ on $n$ variables that has [...] exact quantum query complexity [...] $Q_E(g) = \tilde O(\sqrt n)$.

---

More generally, the complexity class you're looking for is called [EQP: Exact Quantum Polynomial-Time](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#eqp).

EQP is not a very "nice" complexity class, especially compared to BQP. There's two big reasons for that:

1. Theoretical-side, **there's no universal set of gates**. EQP circuits may require a gate with irrational coefficients such as $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(10^\circ) & -\sin(10^\circ)\\ \sin(10^\circ) & \cos(10^\circ)\end{bmatrix}$, and approximations via other gates aren't allowed. So you end up with a bunch of different [$\text{EQP}_{my\_favorite\_gate\_set}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#eqpk)s instead of a nice unified one.
2. Practical-side, **there's no possibility of error correction**. EQP lives in a world without errors, because otherwise it wouldn't be exact. Error correction is expected to be a necessity in practice, so if you care about actual implementation then you don't care much about EQP.

Answer (score 2):

A small modification to Grover's algorithm can make it deterministic. So, you get a quantum algorithm that can search an unsorted database with quadratic speedup compared to a classical computer. Of course, as you pointed out, the usefulness of this algorithm very much depends on the set of gates we are allowed to use.

[You can find the paper on arxiv.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106071)